# Angular 2, RC5 - Form dropdown has additional "ghost" option

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Using Angular 2, RC 5, I am building a form to create a new model object. A dropdown shows the options for the model. When I transpile the code an additional blank <option> shows in the dropdown, though it is not actually created in the DOM. It's as if there is a ghost <option> at the top of the list.

In the following example I have created a model named Example which has the parameters of "id" and "name".

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Example} from './example-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form>
      <h2>Dropdown</h2>

      <select name="name" [(ngModel)]="example.name">
        <option [value]="">Choose one</option>
        <option *ngFor="let option of dropdown" [value]="option.val">
          {{option.name}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </form>
  `,
})

export class AppComponent {
  public example: Example;
  public dropdown: {val: number, name: string}[] = [];

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.example = new Example();
    this.dropdown = this._getDropdownValues();
  }

  private _getDropdownValues(): {val: number, name: string}[] {
    return [
      {val: 10, name: "Name #1"},
      {val: 20, name: "Name #2"},
      {val: 30, name: "Name #3"}
    ];
  }
}
```

Why am I getting a ghost <option> in my dropdown?

You can find the full example on [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4als9Bb5150yUaFPkfOl). I have included some commenters' suggestions for how to fix the problem that unfortunately do not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try and assign a value to your first option. I.e, change this

```
<option [value]="">Choose one</option>
```

to this

```
<option [value]="XX">Choose one</option>
```

Comment: In this case the "Choose one" option needs to have a blank value. How would this work?

Comment: You need to assign a value for this to make you "ghost" option to disappear. You would interpret this in your code and associate "XX" or whatever else you put in there with a blank value.

Answer (score 0):

It's being caused by this line.

```
<option [value]="">Choose one</option>
```

I'm not sure why the text value inside the tags doesn't show initially when the page loads (possibly because of the load event order showing the select element before the model has loaded?), but you're code statically writes this tag into the select, then dynamically adds the additional option tags from your list. If you remove this line the "phantom" value disappears, and if you click it, it will show the intended text value.

I think you're looking for something like this if you do want to keep the choose tag

```
 <option disabled="disabled">Choose one</option>
```

Comment: I tried your approach but it unfortunately doesn't work. Do you have any other suggestions? I updated the Plunkr to show the change you suggested.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "work". I was pointing out where this element comes from, in that it is specified in your code and therefore "expected". As for why it didn't render, my suspicion was correct, and the empty value was caused by the model attribute. Without this part of the select tag, a filled value renders on load. I've edited your plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/6enlftqXAZJrSHcVv0q1?p=preview

Comment: The problem remains when the <select> is attached to the Angular model, in this case [(ngModel)]="example.name". I've updated your plunkr to demonstate: http://plnkr.co/edit/OLeuI5